# Valid JSON can not be parsed depending on server that sends it

Tags: json, api, utf-8

I have a valid JSON response that can and can not be parsed by same requester code depending on the server that sends the response.

Here is the JSON response:

`{"status":200,"message":"Success"}`

In server 1, the response can be parsed by requester. This server sends the response along with this header:

[image: Server that works]

In server 2, the response can NOT be parsed by requester. This server sends the response along with this header:

[image: Server that does not work]

What do you think that may cause the issue?

Comment: The second server's response is longer. Are there some invisible control characters near the end, or at the beginning? (Hint: a BOM is three bytes in UTF-8.)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! That makes sense. Now I'm pretty sure it's BOM issue after reading your comment. The issue is even after I add invisible control characters in my PHP code that sends the response, in the server 1 it still works while in the server 2 it still doesn't work and still contains BOM. How do you handle BOM in the server level?

Comment: Uh, by not having them? UTF-8 doesn't have byte order so the BOM serves no useful purpose, especially in a MIME part whose header already specifies its precise file type and encoding. Some people go so far as to say UTF-8 should never have a BOM, but it can be useful at the beginning of a file if you cannot otherwise know or infer its encoding (typically because your OS is daft, i.e. Windows).